Reusing Azure identity provider for website and API: how to avoid CORS issues due to redirects?
I am running into a CORS error while trying to request an API from a website, due to an identity provider redirect. I have a website running on https://webapp-***.azurewebsites.net and an API running on https://api-***.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/***, the website should be able to make calls to the API.
Both apps are configured with an azureactivedirectory identity provider (in Terraform) and use the same application registration. This works fine: when I go to https://webapp-***.azurewebsites.net, I am redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com/*** to log into a Microsoft tenant. When logged in, I can go to https://api-***.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/*** in a separate tab, and - while redirected for a brief moment - do not have to log in again.
The problem arises when calls are made in the code of the website. Although the API was configured to accept calls from the website's origin, it tries to redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/*** and a CORS error occurs:
Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/***' (redirected from 'https://api-***.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/***') from origin 'https://webapp-***.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is my Terraform configuration:
# Application registration
resource "azuread_application" "api_registration" {
  display_name     = "api-registration-***"
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMyOrg"
  optional_claims {}

  api {
    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "Allow the application to access *** on behalf of the signed-in user."
      admin_consent_display_name = "Access ***"
      enabled                    = true
      type                       = "User"
      user_consent_description   = "Allow the application to access *** on your behalf."
      user_consent_display_name  = "Access ***"
      value                      = "user_impersonation"
      id                         = random_uuid.widgets_scope_id.result
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access {
      id   = "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d" # Sign in and read user profile
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  web {
    homepage_url = "https://api-***.azurewebsites.net"
    redirect_uris = [
      "https://api-***.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback",
      "https://webapp-***.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"
    ]
    implicit_grant {
      id_token_issuance_enabled = true
    }
  }
}

# API app
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "this" {
  name                = "api-***"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.this.id
  tags                = local.tags

  app_settings = {
    "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET" = azuread_application_password.api_client_secret.value
    "WEBSITE_AUTH_AAD_ALLOWED_TENANTS"         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }

  auth_settings_v2 {
    auth_enabled           = true
    require_authentication = true
    runtime_version        = "~2"
    unauthenticated_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"
    default_provider       = "azureactivedirectory"

    active_directory_v2 {
      client_id                  = azuread_application.api_registration.client_id
      client_secret_setting_name = "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET"
      tenant_auth_endpoint       = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id}/v2.0"
    }

    login {
      token_store_enabled = true
    }
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  site_config {
    cors {
      allowed_origins = [
        "https://webapp-***.azurewebsites.net"
      ]
    }
  }
}

# Website app
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp" {
  name                = "webapp-***"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.this.id
  tags                = local.tags

  app_settings = {
    "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET" = azuread_application_password.api_client_secret.value
    "WEBSITE_AUTH_AAD_ALLOWED_TENANTS"         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  auth_settings_v2 {
    auth_enabled           = true
    require_authentication = true
    runtime_version        = "~2"
    unauthenticated_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"
    default_provider       = "azureactivedirectory"

    active_directory_v2 {
      client_id                  = azuread_application.api_registration.client_id
      client_secret_setting_name = "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET"
      tenant_auth_endpoint       = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id}/v2.0"
    }

    login {
      token_store_enabled = true
    }
  }
}

I am struggling to understand how this should be configured.
What configuration should I be looking at to fix this problem? Is there a fundamental flaw in this type of architecture?

I think it's odd that your website (the app running in browser) tries to call login.microsoftonline.com. It's your browser that should change the URL to Microsoft. Once you've obtained the token from the provider then go back to your app as authorized user. If you are looking for m2m auth then do the /token call on the server side. There should be some guides how to configure m2m authentication with EntraId application.

The website is not making calls to login.microsoftonline.com, it is only making calls to the API, but because the API has an identity provider the browser redirects to login.microsoftonline.com and this is causing the CORS error. In effect, I only want users on the tenant to be able to access both website and API.
